# Lower semecontinuity at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an extended value function on $\mathbb R^n$ that is bounded from below, i.e., 
$$f(x)\geq\alpha, \; \forall x \in \mathbb R^n.$$
My question is: Is it true that
$$\liminf_{\|x\|\to +\infty} f(x) \geq \alpha.$$

One of my friend thinks that it should require some thing more like the lower semicontinuuity of $f$. Could any one help me to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

One problem that could occur is that 
$$\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert\to \infty} f(x)$$
might not even exist (depending on what you mean by $\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert\to \infty}$). Usually 
$$\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert\to \infty} f(x) = r \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$$
means that **for every** sequence $(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Vert x_n \Vert \to \infty$ you also have
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = r.$$
It is however not hard to think of functions such that $\liminf f(x_n)$ has different values for different sequences $(x_n)$ (e.g. in which direction are you going to 'infinity').

A more general approach/definition (resulting in less implications) would be to define
$$\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert\to \infty} f(x) := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{\Vert x \Vert \geq n} f(x) $$
This notion of a limes inferior always exists.

**If** $\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert\to \infty} f(x)$ exists, we have 
$$\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert\to \infty} f(x) \geq \alpha$$
for both cases if $f(x) \geq \alpha ~ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{k \geq n} f(x_k)$

Comment: @GenericNickname: Suppose that $f$ is lower semicontinuous on $\mathbb R^n$, how to prove that $\liminf_{\|x\|\to \infty}f(x)$ exists?

Comment: @Richkent Well that's the point. Even if you assume $f$ to be continuous (in particular, semicontinuous) it doesn't imply that $\liminf_{\Vert x \Vert \to \infty} f(x)$ exists. See for example $f(x,y) = e^{x}$, $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is bounded from below by $0$ and $f(-n, y) \to 0$ and $f(n,y) \to \infty$.